# htaccess - check if files exist in current directory and subdirectory, if not redirect to 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to perform an operation in my `.htaccess` file that checks if multiple files exist - and if they don't redirect to a 404 page.

**Request URL:** `//mydomain.com/page-name`

First, it will check if this file exists. If the file does not exist it will check if the file exists in a subdirectory; it will check if the following file exists: `//mydomain.com/h/page-name`.

Lastly, if that file does not exist it will redirect the user to a 404 at: `//mydomain.com/404.php`.

Is it possible to walk through multiple conditions to perform a redirect as I've described here? Is there a better method/solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of messing around I figured it out. Hope it helps someone else! You can place the following code in your `.htaccess` to get achieve this.

```
RewriteEngine On

# if file exists in root directory
# redirect to file in root directory
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  $1  [L,QSA]

# if file exists in /h/ directory
# redirect to file in /h/ directory
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/h/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ h/$1 [L,QSA]

# if we've gotten this far let's just
# send 'em to the 404
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L,QSA]
```